# Error starting AzerothCore - 1046 No database selected

Tags: azerothcore

OS: Ubuntu 22:04, fresh installation of AzerothCore rev. fdbde0b 2024-01-08 20:10:25 +0100 (master branch) (Unix, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon)

authserver starts up fine, but when I launch worldserver, I get the following:

```
Opening DatabasePool ''. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool '' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.

Opening DatabasePool 'acore_characters'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 2.
DatabasePool 'acore_characters' opened successfully. 3 total connections running.

Opening DatabasePool 'acore_world'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_world' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.

[1046] No database selected
Unhandled MySQL errno 1046. Unexpected behaviour possible.
Database Auth is empty, auto populating it...

Applying 'realmcharacters.sql'...
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host '-u' (-2)

Applying of file '/srv/azerothcore/data/sql/base/db_auth/realmcharacters.sql' to database '' failed! If you are a user, please pull the latest revision from the repository. Also make sure you have not applied any of the databases with your sql client. You cannot use auto-update system and import sql files from AzerothCore repository with your sql client. If you are a developer, please fix your sql query.
Could not populate the Login database, see log for details.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_world'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_world' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool 'acore_characters'.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool 'acore_characters' closed.
Closing down DatabasePool ''.
Asynchronous connections on DatabasePool '' terminated. Proceeding with synchronous connections.
All connections on DatabasePool '' closed.
```

Here the logs for authserver:

```
MySQL client library: 3.3.4
MySQL server ver: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Connected to MySQL database at localhost
MySQL client library: 3.3.4
MySQL server ver: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Connected to MySQL database at localhost
DatabasePool 'acore_auth' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.

Database Auth is empty, auto populating it...

Applying 'realmcharacters.sql'...
Applying 'account_banned.sql'...
Applying 'realmlist.sql'...
Applying 'ip_banned.sql'...
Applying 'build_info.sql'...
Applying 'account_muted.sql'...
Applying 'secret_digest.sql'...
Applying 'logs_ip_actions.sql'...
Applying 'account.sql'...
Applying 'autobroadcast.sql'...
Applying 'logs.sql'...
Applying 'updates.sql'...
Applying 'updates_include.sql'...
Applying 'uptime.sql'...
Applying 'account_access.sql'...
Applying 'motd.sql'...
Done!

Updating Auth database...

Applying update "2023_04_24_00.sql" 'D164A70'...
Applied 1 query. Containing 3 new and 32 archived updates.

Started auth database connection pool.
Loading IP Location Database...
```

I've removed the databases, tried again, changed 127.0.0.1 in worldserver and authserver configs to locahost, verified the acore user can log in and has permissions correct

Answer (score -1):

Turns out there was some encoding issue on my worldserver.conf, recompiled, copied the same config out and back in again, worked.